# How can I detect clock skew among nodes in Azure roles?

Tags: azure, p2p, azure-storage, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles

I have a time sensitive operation that needs to be aware of clock skew among other computers, and /or guard against such a thing.  How can I detect or guard against clock skew?

In my case I'm writing a compressed datetime stamp to Azure Blob.  It would be disasterous if different nodes would intererpret that datetime stamp differently (as it can occur during a leap day, or leap second)

---

**More info**

I'm trying to detect clock skew in local node current time.

Each node will be writing time sensitive information to a Blob/Table.  If the timestamp is older than X than certain actions will occur.  If the time is not synchronized, data may be lost or corrupted.

**Possible solution**

Perhaps I can have each node write its current date to blob storage (32 bytes) on a regular interval, and then query that on a routine basis.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few .NET NTP client APIs that will tell you the skew between a local node time and time on a NTP time server. For example:

- Rebex (see ["Determining the time difference between the local time and a time server"](http://www.rebex.net/support/tutorial/time/default.aspx))
- [ComponentSpace](http://www.componentspace.com/products/InternetTime.aspx)
- [ActiveSocket Toolkit](http://www.activexperts.com/activsocket/howto/ntp/vcnet/)

You could use an NTP client to store both the local time and skew in your blob. When you read the blob on a different node, you could compute that node's local time and skew and compare it to the blob's stored time and skew.